# How to fix errors in Camunda trying to make a BPMN?

Tags: diagram, bpmn, processmodel

[Diagram I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3r7b.jpg)
I made this diagram based on a UML diagram i saw here: [The Diagram](https://www.softwareideas.net/a/1661/car-rental-system-uml-activity-diagram-)
But there is a lot of problems here. Can someone tell me how to fix it or i give them the file and correct the necessary things.

It was my first time doing this and i don't know a lot of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using message flows (dashed lines) between process participants as if they represented the control flow, but they don't. Message flows only represent the flow of information. Your process still needs to have a complete control flow (solid lines) from the possible start (s) to the possible (ends).

Maybe you want to learn a bit more about BPMN e.g. here (free): https://academy.camunda.com/page/bpmn